# How to parse excel file

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a lot of rows in excel like

`TALLON | BLACK | 44`

I need to extract **the values between the pipes**.

So, I only need to get the value `BLACK` for the above sample row. How can I extract such values?

Comment: You mention excel, but tag sql and sql-server. What is it that you want? A select statement (SQL) or a column filter (Excel)?

Comment: I added this values from EXCEL in sql table. Now this is table column

Comment: If you want to open an XLS or XLSX file in SQL Server, try [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-data-from-excel-to-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Still then your question is not clear, I guess everything is now in one column, and you want the entire column if it says BLACK between pipes? Of do you want only the value between the pipes? Please clarify what it is that you want.

Comment: value between the pipes

Answer (score 1):

One option would be using `substring()` function with `charindex()` with `|`(pipe) *as expression to search* :

```
with t(str) as
( 
 select 'TALLON | BLACK | 44' union all
 select 'LLON | BLUE| 47   ' union all
 select 'LON    |YELLOW| 56 '   
)
select substring(str, charindex('|',str,1)+1, 
               ( charindex('|',str, charindex('|',str,1)+1) - charindex('|',str,1) )-1 )
       as result             
  from t;

 result
--------
  BLACK
  BLUE
 YELLOW
```

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/UQERY19996)

Comment: I getting error 'Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.'

Comment: @KirillRodeonov actually that should be working but if I produce new rows that might have issues such as yielding `YELLOW|` as result. This new one works for all cases.